# How to interpret double summation with same subscripts

Tags: summation

How would I interpret the following summation (where $r_{k}$ is a function that produces a scalar):
$f^{int}_i = \frac{(\kappa
\mathbf{b})_{i} + (\kappa \mathbf{b})_{i + 1}}{2} \displaystyle\sum_{k=i+1}^{N-2} [r_{k} - \frac{(\kappa
\mathbf{b})_{i - 1} + (\kappa \mathbf{b})_{i}}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{k=i}^{N-2}r_{k}]$

Is using k for both summations just out of laziness? Is this an equivalent function:

$f^{int}_i = \frac{(\kappa
\mathbf{b})_{i} + (\kappa \mathbf{b})_{i + 1}}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{j=i+1}^{N-2} [r_{j} - \frac{(\kappa
\mathbf{b})_{i-1} + (\kappa \mathbf{b})_{i}}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{k=i}^{N-2}r_{k}]$

where $r_{k} = (\boldsymbol{\omega_{i}}-\boldsymbol{\bar{\omega_{i}}})^TB_{i}R_{\pi/2}\boldsymbol{\omega_{i}}$

The original continuous form of the equation is as follows. This quantity is being calculated along a curve. There are two other terms for calculating $f_{int}^{i}$ but I am confident about their translation from the continuous case to the discrete case.

$f^{int}(s) = [(\int_{s}^{L} (\boldsymbol{\omega} - \boldsymbol{\bar{\omega}})^TB(s)R_{\pi/2}\boldsymbol{\omega}dt) (\kappa\mathbf{b})^T]'(s)$

Comment: In my opinion it's not just laziness but actually an incorrect usage as well. How would you know which $k$ matches with which sum?

Comment: What wltrup said. Except I'll say it stronger: The notation is simply wrong. Demand your money back...

Comment: Yes after looking at it more closely, I can tell there are problems with the notation just based on ending up with scalars and vectors for the inner summation (the final quantity should be a vector). I've posted the continuous solution for context.

Answer (score 0):

To me,
the only interpretation which makes sense
is to interpret this as
equivalent to

$$f^{int}_i = \frac{(\kappa
\mathbf{b})_{i-1} + (\kappa \mathbf{b})_{i}}{2} 
\displaystyle\sum_{k=i+1}^{N-2} [r_{k} - \frac{(\kappa
\mathbf{b})_{i-1} + 
(\kappa \mathbf{b})_{i}}{2}
\displaystyle\sum_{j=i}^{N-2}r_{j}]
$$

I would factor things in this way:

$s_i
=\sum_{j=i}^{N-2}r_{j}
$,
$t_i
= \frac{(\kappa
\mathbf{b})_{i-1} + 
(\kappa \mathbf{b})_{i}}{2}
$,
so that

$\begin{array}\\
f^{int}_i
&= t_i \sum_{k=i+1}^{N-2} [r_{k} - t_is_i]\\
&= t_i \sum_{k=i+1}^{N-2} r_{k} -t_i \sum_{k=i+1}^{N-2}  t_is_i\\
&= t_i s_{i+1} -t_i^2s_i (N-2-i)\\
\end{array}
$

This also shows me places
where the formula seems to
have a chance of being in error.
For example,
both the inside sum
and its multiplier
are independent of $k$;
I would look carefully at this.